# log4js para reportes

Tags: nodejs

Buenas a todos pasa que estoy probando esa librería con este código:(adjunto imagen por que no me deja colocar todo el codigo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea de esto es que se imprima un reporte de seguimiento(sobre fallas o funciones que debe cumplir, esto se debe imprimir en un bloc de notas) a un aplicativo, lo que ocurre es que dentro del proyecto si funciona este reporte. Pero cuando genero el instalador y inicio el aplicativo para realizar la prueba de que todo este ok. El reporte nunca se imprime, no se si alguien pueda darme una pista de lo que ocasiona esto :c

Comment: ¿La carpeta `log` existe y es accesible por el mismo usuario que ejecuta el proceso de `node`?

Comment: hola, si, el usuario tiene acceso a la carpeta log en donde están los archivos vucesignature_all y vucesignature.